# Display 2 times of data in mysql

Tags: mysql

My table only has 1 line of data for id ="1".
In my Select query :

```
Select * from table 
where id in(1,2,1)
```

How can i make it to display twice in my output for id=1?

Comment: You need to search for 'self join'

Comment: Although you *can* use tricks like `UNION ALL` to achieve this result, it seems more sensible to handle display issues in application code

Comment: hi guys,so there is no way to make the output to display 2 times ?

Comment: As `Strawberry` mentioned you could use `SELECT * FROM table Where id in (1,2)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table Where id = 1`

Comment: but in my in condition the id may has 3-4 times duplicate.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

well you can use any server side scripting language and process what you get from SQL to repeat for any number of times